# Replace value space with underscore except the last space

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
  function replaceSpaces() 
    {
      var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
      var res = str.replace(" ", "_");
      document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
    }
</script>

<input type="text" value="" name="demo" id="demo" onchange="replaceSpaces()">
```

The Js works like a charm. It replaces the input text value on change from spaces to underscores. 
But would like to restrict the function from adding a space if the user added a space at the end of a string by mistake. **Condition**: One or any number of spaces at the end

Ex:

```
str = 'abc xyz '
```

Expected output = 'abc_xyz'
Current output = 'abc_xyz_'

**UPDATE:**

None of the answers work mentioned below work if the words are more then 2.

For example: 'ab cd ef gh ij '

Comment: str.trim().replace(' ','_');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, `.replace` replaces only the first occurence in the string, as an alternative, you can use this:

```
var res = str.trim().split(/\s+/).join('_')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, trim the string, then replace the spaces.

```
str.replace(/\s+$/g, '').replace(" ", "_");;
```

Answer (score 0):

method `trim()` of a string replaces all whitespace characters from the end and and beginning of a string, so just write :

```
      var res = str.trim().replace(" ", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim first and then replace:

```
var res = string.trim().replace(' ','_');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, some browsers don't support the `trim()` function (IE 8 and under, for instance).

I would recommend you use a regex to do the trim:

```
var res = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').replace(" ", "_");
```

Comment: Try this little change.. `var res = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').replace(/\s+/g, "_")`